# Github's jekyll sitemap generator giving wrong urls for spaces

Tags: github, jekyll, sitemap

One of the urls for my page is:

> http://blog.theofekfoundation.org/general%20computer%20programming/2015/12/30/2d-array-copy-speeds.html
>   (note the %20s)

While the jekyll sitemap entry is:

```
<loc>
    http://blog.theofekfoundation.org/general%2520computer%2520programming/2015/12/30/2d-array-copy-speeds.html
</loc> # Note the %2520s
```

I added the sitemap using github's sitemap gem:

```
gems:
 - jekyll-sitemap
```

in my _config.yml.

Any idea what's going wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, `jekyll-sitemap` always encode the URLs and is not smart enough to detect that the URL already contains encoded text, which is causing it to encode the `%` character (hence the `%25`).

You can [open an issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap/issues) on the `jekyll-sitemap` repository, and see if there are any plans to improve this story.

However, if that is an option, I would recommend you to not use spaces, and instead use a dash `-`, which is more user-friendly and easier to read... With the added benefit that it doesn't break the sitemap.

Also, get rid of the .html at the end.

e.g.
http://blog.theofekfoundation.org/general-computer-programming/2015/12/30/2d-array-copy-speeds/

Comment: thanks! I changed by spaces to dashes as you suggested. how do I remove the .html? jekyll compiles my .md files automatically, eg:
2015-12-30-2d-array-copy-speeds.md

Thanks so much!

Comment: Great! To remove the `.html` in the end, you just have to configure the `permalink` inside your `_config.yml` file to a pattern that doesn't include the `.html`. Take a look at the `pretty` pattern, for example: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/